# style is not applied at runtime but being applied at design time in wpf

Tags: wpf, resourcedictionary

I have a simple style in a resource dictionary which is located in a WPFResources.dll, I am accessing this style in another project, I can see that the style is being applied at design time, but when i run the application I am getting an exception that `"Cannot find resource named 'IndentCheckBoxStyle'. Resource names are case sensitive"`. if i use the StaticResource then I can see this exception if I use the DynamicResource then I dont see any exception, but nothing is visible on the UI.

More about this issue:

I have referenced the WPFResources.dll in my project and merged it in the App.XAML like this:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/WPFResources;component/Theme.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>        
    </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
```

And inside the Theme.xaml i have merged the resource dictionary of the cheboxstyle.

Any one have any idea about this ??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about you post the related code?

Comment: Is WPFResources.dll available in the application bin path?

Comment: Yes it is in Bind folder and i have added in the App.XAML

Comment: If you solved your problem then please post the answer, I have the same problem and now I have no idea how you solved it.

Comment: I have missed some of brush resources which are referenced by the IndentCheckboxStyle inside the WPFResources.dll.

Answer (score 1):

I've had this problem and found that the styles were being applied to the entire application using the Pack URI syntax,

e.g. in App.xaml

```
<Application x:Class="Framework.Presentation.Preview.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
         <ResourceDictionary>
             <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Abt.Framework.Presentation;component/Themes/AbtDark.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
         </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

However, an implicit style is not being applied to the top level window in the application (despite MyTheme.xaml containing an unnamed Style for Window)

To resolve this, I've simply used a named style (not implicit style) for the Window. The rest are applying correctly.